# Replace part of URL within PHP variable

Tags: php

I am using PHP to set the current URL as a variable using

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This would echo the string:

http://www.example.com/landing-page-demo/

I would like to replace the 'landing-page' part of the string with 'confirmation-page' and then save this updated URL as another variable.

I was thinking of using str replace, is this the most ideal method of doing this? Not sure how to approach the problem

Comment: Sounds good. <extra characters go here>

Comment: I believe you can do this by using core string function.use to replace sub-string .Have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, short of knowing regular expressions, str_replace will do the trick.

Perform str_replace on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Example:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace("landing", "confirmation", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution using Str Replace:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Full URL var
$redirecturl = str_replace("landing","confirmation", $url);
```

Comment: Yes that is possible. You could also have called str_replace() on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and placed directly within your assignment statement. I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Using str_replace is the easiest solution however you can do your logic with  `pathinfo($url)`

```
    $url = "http://www.example.com/landing-page-demo/";
    $newURL = str_replace('landing', 'confirmation', $url);
    echo $newURL;
```